# AmCharts info balloon not showing when bullet is hovered

Tags: javascript, amcharts

I am having some trouble getting information balloons to show up on my [AM Chart](https://www.amcharts.com/). Here is my chart object settings. At the moment I can see a round bullet on the chart but nothing happens when I hover over it. I have followed the following guides in the [documentation](https://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmBalloon) without any luck. I am using AM Charts v3.11.3 if that helps.  If anyone can let me know what I may be missing I'd really appreciate it.

```
var AmChartsConfig = {
        type: 'serial',
        theme: 'light',
        titles: [{
          text: config.title.text,
          size: config.title.size
        }],
        dataDateFormat: 'YYYY-MM',
        valueAxes: [{
          id: 'v1',
          axisAlpha: 0,
          position: 'left'
        }],
        balloon: {
          borderThickness: 1,
          shadowAlpha: 0
        },
        graphs: [{
          id: 'g1',
          bullet: 'round',
          bulletBorderAlpha: 1,
          bulletColor: '#FFFFFF',
          bulletSize: 5,
          hideBulletsCount: 50,
          lineThickness: 2,
          title: 'red line',
          useLineColorForBulletBorder: true,
          valueField: 'value',
          balloonText: '<div style="margin:5px; font-size:19px;"><span style="font-size:13px;">[[category]]</span><br>[[value]]</div>'
        }],
        categoryField: 'date',
        categoryAxis: {
          parseDates: false,
          dashLength: 1,
          minorGridEnabled: true
        },
        export: {
          enabled: true
        },
        dataProvider: data
      };
```

Comment: Can you add the full javascript, i.e the code for when you create the chart, such as `var chart = AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", { etc...` The format of your balloon text is perfectly fine, so your problem lies elsewhere.

Comment: The function using the `AmCharts.makeChart` method isn't anything very special. It just takes an `element` and the `config` like so `function generateAmCharts(element, AmChartsConfig) {
      chartId++;
      element.attr('id', chartId);
      return AmCharts.makeChart(chartId, AmChartsConfig);
    }`

Comment: I concur with pokeybit - your config looks fine and the balloons are triggering just fine [in this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vwu8f0x5/). Can you try to reproduce the problem in a fiddle so we can better help you?

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce the issue in jsfiddle. Since the code works fine as is the problem must be something deeper. I will keep looking and hopefully track down what the problem is. Thanks again for the help.